# How to insert a line into text document right before line containing some text in bash?

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have a variable say `$strToInsert` and I have a file `file.html`. I wonder how to find the last appearance of `</head>` and insert a new line before the line with it and fill it with `$strToInsert` contents?

Here is what I have:

```
GACODE="UA-00000000-1"

if [ "$2" = "" ]
then
    echo "Usage: $0 <url to extract doxygen generated docs into> <GA tracker code if needed>"
    echo "Using default"
else
    GACODE = $2
fi

GASTR="<script>var _gaq = _gaq || [];_gaq.push([\'_setAccount\', \'$GACODE\']);_gaq.push([\'_trackPageview\']);(function() {var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript\'; ga.async = true;ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);})();</script>"
```

but when I try:

```
sed -i 's#</head>#'$GASTR'\n</head>#' header.html
```

I get:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 21: unterminated `s' command
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: You need to protect $GASTR by putting it in double-quotes:  `"$GASTR"` ... otherwise spaces are a problem.... Often, you can put the entire sed expression in double quotes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sed -i "s#</head>#$strToInsert\n</head>#" file.html
```

but I'm not sure is "last appearence" means you can have several `</head>` in your file?

Comment: But I have some strange  problems I described in post update.

Comment: it is due to `'` inside your variable. I've just updated my answer and replaced all `'` to `"`. Now it works fine.

Answer (score 5):

```
sed "/<\/head>/i\
$strToInsert" file.html
```

This will insert the new line before *every* `</head>`, but why do you have more than one?

Answer (score 3):

```
cat "$file" #(before)
1
2 </head>
3
4 </head>
5
6 </head>
```

---

```
strToInsert="hello world"
lnum=($(sed -n '/<\/head>/=' "$file"))  # make array of line numbers
((lnum>0)) && sed -i "${lnum[$((${#lnum[@]}-1))]}i \
                      $strToInsert" "$file"
```

---

```
cat "$file" #(after)
1
2 </head>
3
4 </head>
5
hello world
6 </head>
```