# How to add some text before another with sed in FreeBSD?

Tags: sed, freebsd

How to add some text before another with sed?
With GNU sed on linux I can make it like that:

```
sed -i "/\;Marker/i some text" conffile
```

It puts "*some text*" before "*;Marker*". But in FreeBSD I get an error:

> sed: 1: "/conffile ...": extra characters at the end of l command

I need analog to use it in FreeBSD.

Comment: see https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Commands-Requiring-a-newline

Comment: @Sundeep, GNU sed, really?

Comment: check again, it gives POSIX solution too :)

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/35227/22142 is one of the many posts that answer your question...

Comment: echo "Marker" | sed "s/.*/praveen&/g" here I am adding Praveen before marker and it worked fine

Comment: output praveenMarker

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add headers to columns](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/401670/how-to-add-headers-to-columns) and see [my this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/401695/72456) there.

Comment: Here, too, note that `sed` takes the `conffile` argument as commands to run, since `-i` eats the actual script.

Comment: @don_crissti No duplicate. It answers their question, but not their problem. (-:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found this way:

```
sed -i'' -e $'/Marker/i\\\nblahblah\\\n' file
```

or

```
sed -i'' -e '/Marker/i\'$'\n''blahblah'$'\n' file
```

Comment: I think you only need to add an argument to the `-i` option, the rest of the script looks okay to me: `sed -i '' '/;Marker/i some text' conffile`. If your own answer works, accept it to close the question.

Comment: That syntax does not work on FreeBSD `sed`. @Philippos